# Auto-load gfm-mode

Tags: emacs, markdown, aquamacs

I have installed *markdown-mode.el* as described [here](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/).  How do I get Emacs (specifically, Aquamacs) to load `gfm-mode` rather than `markdown-mode` for `.markdown` files?  In case it's important, the relevant section(s) of my *~/.emacs* currently look(s) like this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")

; Some irrelevant (I think) other stuff

(autoload 'markdown-mode "markdown-mode.el" "Major mode for editing Markdown files" t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.text\\'" . markdown-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.md\\'" . markdown-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mdown\\'" . markdown-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mdt\\'" . markdown-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.markdown\\'" . markdown-mode))
```

I'm extremely noobish with Emacs in general, so I'd appreciate step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing the lines you posted with these:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")

;;; Markdown mode
(autoload 'gfm-mode "markdown-mode.el" "Major mode for editing Markdown files" t)
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.text$" . gfm-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.md$" . gfm-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.mdown$" . gfm-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.mdt$" . gfm-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.markdown$" . gfm-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

The important thing is to add `'gfm-mode` before `"markdown-mode.el"` in the `autoload` command.

Comment: That just does the same thing as my current *.emacs*.  I wanted it to load gfm-mode rather than markdown-mode.

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame, sorry, I misunderstood your question. It should work now.

Comment: That doesn't work at all, unless something else entirely is wrong:  I get *fill-mode* when I shouldn't, and syntax highlighting in code fences is not active.

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame, that I can't help you with. Perhaps the mode is not what you expect. Does emacs say it is in gfm-mode in the status bar? If yes, then the mode has been successfully loaded.

Comment: It does say it's in *gfm-mode*, but it behaves like it's in standard `markdown-mode`.  I guess you answered my question as stated.